# how to collect all muted feed item list in salesforce soql

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, salesforce-chatter

Hi all I currently working in the salesforce community portal in my case I want to get all muted feed posts in one list. I tried but unable to find the proper SOQL to get all muted and unmuted feed post lists.help anyone how to handle it.